# MVC4 won't pass Model to Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model

I'm trying to pass a C# object as a parameter back to the controller. It's done like this:

```
@model Models.AdvancedSearchTerms

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Loading";
}    


@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Keyword) 

@using (Html.BeginForm("MetaSearch", "AdvancedSearch", new { term = Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <input id="startGatheringData" type="Submit" name="Convert" />
}
```

As you see I try to send the whole model back to controller if the button is pushed. But when the method in the controller gets the Model it is null. To ensure that the Model is not empty in the View, you can see that I've tried to print a variabel using the  @Html.DisplayFor, and it works. So the Model is not empty in the View, but disappears when I pass it to the controller:

```
 public ActionResult MetaSearch(AdvancedSearchTerms term)
    {

       //Do stuff with the model retrived from the View() 
        return View() 
    }
```

Anyone got any idea why this object is empty? I've done this a lot and have no idea why it is not working this time. I've also tried to only pass a single variabel, but this is also Null.

In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create input fields for this inside the form, if you don't want to show them to user use Hidden Fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MetaSearch", "AdvancedSearch", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SomeProperty)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SomeProperty)

    <input id="startGatheringData" type="Submit" name="Convert" />
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was afraid so. I was just hoping it was an easier way out :)
I will try it in a while and then accept this answer if it works! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it works, and I will use this for now. I will probably change this to a more efficient way as soon as possible, but for i just need a quick fix! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

---

## Sending A Single Value to Controller

---

I've literally just been creating a 'search'/filter option in my form; Using something like:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <hr />
        Search
        <hr />
        Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @id = "thisID" })<a style="float:right; margin-top:8px" href="@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="subBtn" />
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

With my controller code Being:

```
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Traders.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {

            var traders = from m in db.Traders    //db is my Database Entities
                       select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                traders = traders.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(traders);
        }
```

And so my controller will receive this textBox value as part of the method.

---

## Filtering Using Search and/or Combo box (both or one or none)

---

I actually used [this site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-search) to implement a basic search/filtering system for my project. It helped SO MUCH.

It uses `ViewBag` to allow you to create a comboBox which you can then select and return the selected value to your [HttpPost] action method - great for your filtering/searching needs!

This means that instead of sending a full Model back to your controller, you pass instead a 'search term', which you can then use in your controller method - and easily getting matching models in your method (similar to sending a single value as in first example).

Your action method could then look like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
{
    var GenreLst = new List<string>();

    var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                   orderby d.Genre
                   select d.Genre;

    GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

    var movies = from m in db.Movies
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
    }

    return View(movies); //returns movies matching results
}
```

---

## Sending a Full Model To Controller

---

In terms of help passing a *full* controller, you may find [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) helpful, as it creates basic CRUD actions (the 'Create' allows you to pass a single model to controller).

In the 'PostBack' Action method, you would need to 'bind' the data, like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate")]Student student)
{
//do stuff with this model
return redirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is further explained in the link above.

Comment: Seems perfect for OPs Question :)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: OP is implementing a search facility (from variable names, anyway). Also, It shows/teaches the OP how to pass data from View to controller, whether or not all fields are complete (otherwise your model may need to be changed to allow NULL values) ;)

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. OP is trying to pass the whole model via a route parameter - there are no textboxes or "search/filters" involved

Comment: I suggest you read my last example again (true, it hasn't much in terms of content (yet), but does allow you to send a full model to your controller).

Comment: Hey and thanks! Very interesting code and valuable feedback from you! I can use a lot of this in my current project. I went for Ehsan Sajjad answer as a temporary solution! But thanks for the help!  I will probably change this to a more efficient way as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use information from a view in the controller again be sure to make the action a httppost action

like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MetaSearch(AdvancedSearchTerms term)
{
//LOGIC
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its there. I've just removed it by some reason in the presented code

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do this if you model contains only simple properties (no collections or complex objects)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MetaSearch", "AdvancedSearch", Model, FormMethod.Post, null))
```

however why would you do this. Your just degrading performance by posting back a whole lot of values in the query string it generates. Its far better to just post back the unique ID of the model and get the model again from the database in you controller.

**Edit**

In addition, the model cannot contain a property with the same name as a route parameter. For example if you have defined a route with `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` the model cannot contain a property named `ID`.